# How to let the angularjs controller run only once even many ng-controllers defined in DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I wish I can handle this, but in the bad way...namely I need to use `$cookieStore` to check either the function called or not.

Every time to use `push` array then I need to use `$cookieStore`. But it seems not practical.

Here was my DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
     <div ng-include="'temp2.html'">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp2.html">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">Another View</div>
</script>
```

And my angularjs controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    alert(1);
}
```

`alert(1)` function will be called 2 times every times the page was called.

How to avoid this problem without using watcher?

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imranhamzah/Lvc0u55v/12550/) for your convenience. Thanks!

Comment: you are using same controller twice , so its instantiating twice for two div . Is this how you are using it ?

Comment: I need to called it twice since the controller cannot understand which views  in my ng-include.

Comment: NO, your view can understand which controller it should follow

Comment: Ok2..I just need the solution for this problem to avoid this things to happen. I will research back deep later about what you've said. Thanks.

Comment: please check the answer i provided.

Answer (score 0):

The controller would called be twice for both the views, i would suggest you to move `controller` specific code to `init` function and use `ng-init` in one of your `views`.

```
var Controller = function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function () {
  };
};
```

Your View

```
<div ng-controller="Controller" ng-init="init()"/>
```

Comment: Ok..I want to try first. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Imran: cool.. in one of your view you could use ng-init and in other you can avoid, by keeping this you can ensure some code is not initialized in one of your view though available.

Comment: How to implement your code? I do not know how to use it. Can you show me on this fiddle?
http://jsfiddle.net/imranhamzah/Lvc0u55v/12581/

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to specify the Controller name again in the include.... if its the same as the parent one(same as controller of main page).

just go with this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>
     <div ng-include="'temp2.html'">
    Hello, {{name}}!
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp2.html">
    <div>Another View {{name}}</div>
</script>
```

[Js Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/ey0toqge/)

**name** will be accessible in the view you included.

Hope it will help you..